# Mikva immersion with stoma (respiratory tube)

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

Some cancer patients have a [stoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracheotomy). This means they don't breathe through their mouth or nose but through a tube cut into their throat. It is covered by a filter which has to be changed daily. Water getting into the tube would go straight to the lung which would be fatal. It is not really a tube but the original airway cut into the throat. Some do have a tube fitted to keep it open but it is not always necessary.

**How can such patients immerse into a mikva?** I suppose it is possible to straight away pump the water out, but it still would be very dangerous. Although this is not necessarily a halacha question but more likely a practical question it is still very relevant.

Comment: Offhand, I'm not sure if full immersion is needed. I.e., you might fulfill the requirement without immersing your head. If this is permitted, would this solve the problem for you?

Comment: @DanF no part of the body can be above water. Parts could sometimes be covered and be underwater (cf. the laws of Chatzitza), but never above water.

Comment: This case seems very similar to R Moshe's case of water in her ears

Comment: Could the tube be covered during immersion? Wouldn't work with a finger but maybe the tube can be closed for a few seconds?

Comment: Sounds like a question for your [local Orthodox rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).

Comment: How about a stoma snorkel?
http://www.thelarysnorkelstore.com/Snorkeling-Equipment.html

Comment: I allowed myself to edit your question to make it less personal - otherwise it would very likely have been closed since MY doesn't offer personalized advice. For this one has to speak to a rav who knows the patient and his/her situation well. You can always further [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/87173/edit) or rollback to get your original question back. And [welcome to MiYodeya!](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites)

Comment: You seem to also have deleted my other comment about using a snorkel. If the tube is closed one cannot breathe and whatever you close it with may be considered a chatsitsa. I must add that one breathes through the normal airway which has been cut at the throat although I called it a tube. So there is no chatsitsa there. The problem is really how to stop water getting in while immersing. Although I am a man the problem of course pertains more for a woman.

Comment: @patient I didn’t delete any comment of yours, only moderators can do so and I doubt they did. Maybe you didn’t submit it fully. Thanks for re submitting it, it makes things clearer